# Мнемоника not в ассемблере и оперативная память

Tags: x86_64, x86, ассемблер, i686

Всем здравствуйте!
Известно, ассемблер не позволяет копировать данные из оперативной памяти в неё же (L1, L2 - метки):

```
mov [L1], [L2] ; ошибка
```

Вопрос: Тогда почему разрешена следующая команда?

```
not byte [L1]
```

Для этого ведь одновременно нужно считывать из памяти и записывать в неё. А RAM позволяет выполнять только одну операцию за раз. Значит промежуточные результаты где-то хранятся? Регистры общего назначения после этой инструкции не изменились.

Comment: > Регистры общего назначения после этой инструкции не изменились.

Реальных регистров в процессоре больше, чем вы видите в отладчике.

Comment: Обе команды работают по одной схеме.
Чтение из памяти в регистр -> выполнение действий -> запись обратно в память. Чем первая команда в этом плане сложнее?

Comment: @asv, при выполнении одной машинной операции может выполняться несколько микроопераций, физически нет запрета на "одновременный" (на самом деле последовательный) доступ к памяти. Фактически запрещены только операции, использующие 2 *явно* заданных операнда, находящихся в памяти (такие операции просто просто отсутствуют в системе команд процессоров x86). Почему именно явно заданные - почитайте про операции movs, cmps и иже с ними, они обращаются к двум операндам в памяти, адреса которых неявно заданы через регистры esi, edi.

Comment: Андрей, вообще-то позволяет, суть функции прямого копирования из ячейки памяти по указателю [esi] в в ячейку по указателю [edi] с постинкрементом обоих указателей.

Answer (score 1):

*(Превращу свой древний комментарий в ответ)*

При выполнении одной машинной операции может выполняться несколько микроопераций, физически нет запрета на "одновременный" (на самом деле последовательный) доступ к памяти. Фактически запрещены только операции, использующие 2 явно заданных операнда, находящихся в памяти (такие операции просто просто отсутствуют в системе команд процессоров x86). Почему - потому что так спроектировали инженеры Intel.

Есть операции `movs`, `cmps` и другие подобные, которые обращаются "одновременно" к двум адресам в памяти, которые неявно заданы через регистры `esi`, `edi`.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то архитектура x86 процессоров позволяет копировать данные напрямую из памяти (ОЗУ) в память в обход звгрузки в регистры общего назначения. Суть функции прямого копирования из ячейки памяти по указателю [esi] в в ячейку по указателю [edi] с постынкрементом обоих указателей.

Что касается операции отрицания, то она, как водится, выполняется на инверторе. Общая схема такая:

1. Загрузка данных из памяти в АЛУ (в современных процессорах он почти не отличим от самого процессора %).
2. Выполнения операции отрицания.
3. Сохранение результата в память по тому же адресу.

Answer (score 0):

Короткий ответ - потому что когда команда переводиться в [бинарный вид](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#mov), то там нет места для двух адресов в памяти. Поэтому команда mov не может работать с двумя ячейками в памяти, а not - умеет. По этой же причине mov не умеет работать с регистром IP (адрес команды в памяти).